# Redux-Saga and Superagent

Tags: javascript, ajax, redux, redux-saga, superagent

I need to make a request to my API endpoint to upload a file. I use axios across my project, but it looks like it's a problem to attach a file with it, while it should be straightforward with Superagent. However, my Saga code doesn't work with Superagent(no response object, API isn't triggered) What am I doing wrong?

```js
import { delay } from 'redux-saga';
import { select, call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import request from 'superagent'
import * as action from '../../constants/actions/';
import config from '../../constants/config';
import { getFile, selectEntity, selectPreview } from '../../selectors';

export default function* putUserpic() {
   const file = yield select(getFile)
   const API = process.env.API_URL || config.API_URL;

   const entity = yield select(selectEntity);
   const requestURL = `${API}/${entity}/userpic`;
   const token = localStorage.getItem(config.TOKEN);



    var req = request.post(requestURL)
    .attach(file.name, file)
    .set('authorization', token);


    try {
      yield put({type: action.REQ_PENDING});
      const response = yield call(req.end)
      yield put({type: action.RES_RECEIVED})
      yield put({type: action.MESSAGE, payload: response.data.message});

    } catch (e) {
       yield put({type: action.RES_RECEIVED})
       yield put({type: action.AUTH_ERROR, payload: e.response.data.error});
       yield delay(config.MSG_DELAY);
       yield put({type: action.RESET_ERROR})
    } finally {
       yield delay(config.MSG_DELAY);
       yield put({type: action.RESET_MESSAGE})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use react sagas `call`-effect to call something that **returns a promise**. In your case, you're asking it to run *the end-function, which is intended to be used with callbacks* when you don't want to use promises. If you remove the end from your call line, you should see a request being made and should be getting a response:

```
const response = yield call(req)
```

Here you can find more about how to work with promises in superagent:
http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#promise-and-generator-support